# Which server actually runs the SSIS package when SQL Agent and SSISDB are on 2 different servers

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

We have a SQL Server where we deployed the SSIS packages to its Integration Service Catalog (SSIS DB).
And we have another SQL Server where we scheduled SQL Agent to run those SSIS packages.
My question, where does the SSIS package execution actually happens? The SQL Agent server, or the Integration Service Catalog?

A little background of why we are doing/asking this: we have an old SQL Server where we deployed a lot of legacy SSIS packages. Now we have a new SQL Server where we plan to move to, but we don't want to move those legacy SSIS packages. So we are trying to just move some SQL Agent jobs to the new server to call those legacy SSIS. With some research, we thought the execution happens on the SQL Agent server, but the log says it's on the SSIS DB server. However, the execution failed and complain missing ZappySys component, which looks like the execution happened on the SQL Agent server, because we indeed don't have ZappySys component on the SQL Agent server. We are so confused now......

Comment: Could post detailed error about ZappySys component and how you execute it from Agent? Security can be an issues here.

Comment: My guess is that it's a context issue.  Make sure that the account running SQL Agent on the new server is the same as the one who did it on the old one. Also check for proxy on the old agent jobs (make sure the SSIS packages weren't running under a different user).

Answer (score 2):

SSIS packages deployed to  to its Integration Service Catalog (SSIS DB) will run on the server where SSIS service and SSISDB in installed.

Comment: Could you back that up, e.g. with a link to documentation?